# Prevent Apex setCookies prepend prefix 'apex_'

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, guest-user, cookies

Hi guys as may already know salesforce changed [Debug logs for Site Guest User](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000247187&language=en_US) in winter 17. And I ran into a problem, I can't set the cookies from current page controller (Apex Controller), I get the cookies but with a prefix, in this case "apex_".

So my question, is there anyway to prevent Apex code prepend that prefix on my cookie name?

Here is the code I'm using. (I can't set document.cookie from JS, since current apex page content type is text/xml)

```
Apexpages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{
    new Cookie('debug_logs', 'debug_logs', null, -1, false),
    new Cookie('domain', '.force.com', null, -1, false)
});
```

Comment: Why not set it from the client side instead? Just use `Javascript`.

Comment: I can't set document.cookie from JS, since current apex page content type is text/xml. And I'm using the force.com site as an endpoint... I forgot add that.

Comment: Are you able to [set a cookie using html](http://www.willmaster.com/library/cookies/setting-a-cookie-using-only-html.php)?

Comment: The Cookie class always uses `apex__` as a prefix. This applies to reading *and* writing cookies. It's a security feature. You'll need to find anther way to work around the problem. Speaking of which, why *is* this a problem?